# Creating Proportional Graphs in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to create a proportional bar graph in R. I have two variables, one is "drunk" and one is "housing“。I want to graph the proportional of individuals of each category of " housing" who fulfil "drunk".

The dataframe is something like follows:

Drunk: 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
Housing: 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1

I want to know how to graph the proportion of each category of housing (1 through 4) which fulfils "1" for drunk.

> png("Graphs/Analysis_Figure1.png")
>
> analysis %>%
>
> count(housing, drunk) %>%
>
> group_by(housing) %>%
>
> mutate(freq = n/sum(n)) %>%
>
> ggplot(aes(x = housing, y = freq, fill = drunk)) +
>
> geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'dodge')
>
> dev.off()

This gives me the proportions, but instead of only including "1" responses for drunk, I also get "0". Is there a way to only include 1?

[This is an image I generated with STATA, which I hope to replicate inN R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i2x9.png)

[This is what I get with R instead. I want to remove the "2 or less" (coded as "0" drunk responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNkc1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` function from `dplyr` in your pipleline:

```
analysis %>%
filter(drunk == 1) %>%
count(housing, drunk) %>% ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This one worked. I'm wondering how I would do it if I wanted to further separate them into categories, for example I want to add a new category of "hsdrunk", and then divide it into two categories？